# How to remove a level from the columns of a dataframe produced by pivot_table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

### The issue

I have a dataset that looks like the toy example below.

I need to create a table that sums the value for each combination of item and period, and displays it in a crosstab / pivot table format.

If I use `pandas.crosstab()` I get the output I want.

**If I use `pandas.pivot_table` I get what seems like a multi-level index for the columns.**

**How can I get rid of the multi-level index?**

Yes, I could use just `crosstab`, but():

1. in general, I want to learn about multi-level indices
2. sometimes I
   don't have the 'raw' data and I receive the data in the format
   produced by pivot_table

### What I have tried

I have tried `totals_pivot_table.droplevel(0`) but it says there is only one level. What does this mean?

dataframe.columns.droplevel() is no longer supported

### Example tables

This is the output of pivot_table:

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|        | value | value | value | value |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| period |     1 |     2 |     3 | All   |
| item   |       |       |       |       |
| x      |    10 |    11 |    12 | 33    |
| y      |    13 |    14 |    15 | 42    |
| All    |    23 |    25 |    27 | 75    |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

This is what I need:

```
+------+----+----+----+-----+
| item | 1  | 2  | 3  | All |
+------+----+----+----+-----+
| x    | 10 | 11 | 12 |  33 |
| y    | 13 | 14 | 15 |  42 |
| All  | 23 | 25 | 27 |  75 |
+------+----+----+----+-----+
```

### Toy code

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['item'] = np.repeat(['x','y'],3)
df['period'] = np.tile([1,2,3],2)
df['value'] = np.arange(10,16)

pivot = df.pivot(index ='item', columns ='period', values = None)

totals_pivot_table = df.pivot_table(index ='item', columns = 'period', aggfunc ='sum', margins = True)

totals_ct = pd.crosstab( df['item'], df['period'], values =df['value'] , aggfunc ='sum', margins=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Better is specified `values` parameter:

```
totals_pivot_table = df.pivot_table(index ='item', 
                                    columns = 'period', 
                                    values='value', 
                                    aggfunc ='sum', 
                                    margins=True)

print (totals_pivot_table)
period   1   2   3  All
item                   
x       10  11  12   33
y       13  14  15   42
All     23  25  27   75
```

If not possible is possible use [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html), but be carefull for duplicated columns names:

```
print (totals_pivot_table.droplevel(0, axis=1))
period   1   2   3  All
item                   
x       10  11  12   33
y       13  14  15   42
All     23  25  27   75
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['item'] = np.repeat(['x','y'],3)
df['period'] = np.tile([1,2,3],2)
df['value'] = np.arange(10,16)
df['value1'] = np.arange(7,13)
print (df)
  item  period  value  value1
0    x       1     10       7
1    x       2     11       8
2    x       3     12       9
3    y       1     13      10
4    y       2     14      11
5    y       3     15      12

totals_pivot_table = df.pivot_table(index ='item', 
                                    columns = 'period', 
                                    aggfunc ='sum', 
                                    margins=True)

print (totals_pivot_table)
       value             value1            
period     1   2   3 All      1   2   3 All
item                                       
x         10  11  12  33      7   8   9  24
y         13  14  15  42     10  11  12  33
All       23  25  27  75     17  19  21  57

print (totals_pivot_table.droplevel(0, axis=1))
period   1   2   3  All   1   2   3  All
item                                    
x       10  11  12   33   7   8   9   24
y       13  14  15   42  10  11  12   33
All     23  25  27   75  17  19  21   57
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reset_index() on making your df totals_ct

```
totals_ct.index
```

gives:

```
Index(['x', 'y', 'All'], dtype='object', name='item')
```

However, using reset_index() when making totals.ct gets rid of all the three indexes

```
totals_ct = pd.crosstab( df['item'], df['period'], values =df['value'] , aggfunc ='sum', margins=True).reset_index()
```

check for result:

```
totals_ct.index
```

gives:

```
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
```

maybe this is what you are looking for.

greetings Jan